# luajit mode with C API

Tags: lua, luajit

I'm starting at LUAJIT.

LUAJIT has a function to set mode

```
LUA_API int luaJIT_setmode(lua_State *L, int idx, int mode);
```

Is there any way to get actual mode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can do that, and I'm not sure if this is an option for you, but you could edit `src/lj_dispatch.c`, and add (untested):

```
int luaJIT_getmode(lua_State *L, int idx) {
  global_State *g = G(L);
  return G2J(g)->flags;
}
```

and you would add a definition into `luajit.h`. I don't think this is very pragmatic, but in the spirit of `const_cast` I see no reason for it not to work. Suggest avoiding the need to do this though...